# Umbraco: Check if current page is child of page with id or name of 'xxx'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I need to check if the current page is a child of another page.

```
var myPage = Umbraco.Content(1086);
if(Model.IsChildOf(myPage)) {  }   ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking :-)

```
if(Model.Path.Contains("1086")) {
  //.. the page is a child of the node with id == 1086
}
```

Or

```
var myPage = Umbraco.Content(1086);
if(Model.Path.Contains(myPage.Id.ToString())) { 
  // It's a child!
}
```

Comment: I used option 1, thanks